# creating temp queues in grails, creating a lot of temp queues

Tags: multithreading, grails, queue, jms

i can't seem to find any samples on this.. can someone help?

and is this good design?

in my grails app, every user can create their own queues (temp queues - assuming i know how to create them).. so let's assume that there will be 100,000 users using the web app.. the consumer will be a stand alone java app. the java app will be a consumer of a permanent queue/topic.. that queue/topic will be for the "commands" to create an object that will consume the temporarily created queues. and then the users will send/receive messages (i might use the examples in activemq as template for the codes.. i need to implement them as runnables for each user).

and does having a lot of temp queues ok?

thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you explain the Use Case in detail. Why do you need a queue for each user? Why do you need queues at all? Sounds a bit odd at the first look.

Answer (score 0):

A good example for implementing a Request/Reply Scenario using JMS is in the ActiveMQ documentation as you already stated: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

However if you are really talking about 100.000 users you should do some performance and stability testing ahead. Maybe it would be a better idea to pool the temporary queues and reuse them everytime. Another possibility might be to use only few queues and select the appropriate messages with a MessageSelector, by assigning some unique id as messages property.